# How to register a Windows 7 device to Azure AD

Tags: windows-7, azure, entra-id

I'm trying to register a Windows 7 device to Azure AD, and I am at a loss as to how to do this...

I have already created an Azure AD directory, created a user, and verified that they have permissions to register devices (up to 20).

**I already understand how to do this with a Windows 10 device by using the "Join Azure AD" button under System->About. Is there anything similar to this feature found in Windows 7 devices?**

[Alex Belotserkovskiy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1963868/alex-belotserkovskiy) was kind enough to provide this link: [Configure automatic device registration for Windows 7 domain joined devices](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/active-directory-conditional-access-automatic-device-registration-windows7/).  I tried to download the "downloadable MSI package" but it leads to this [site](https://connect.microsoft.com/site1164) with a link to "Download Workplace Join for Windows 7" that does not work for me.  Every time I click it while already logged in I get the following message:

*Page Not Found 
The content that you requested cannot be found or you do not have permission to view it. 
If you believe you have reached this page in error, click the Help link at the top of the page to report the issue and include this ID in your e-mail: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx*

I did send a message to Microsoft yesterday, and I'm still waiting for a reply.  If I do get a reply I'll be sure to post.  But, in the meantime, does anyone know how to register a Windows 7 device to Azure AD?  ...And perhaps without this Microsoft hassle?

Any help, suggestions, clarification, or elaboration is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Azure AD is not a fully functional domain, in it's default form it is mainly just a user and group store, which you cannot join machines to. Windows 10 has some special features that allow you to join to an Azure AD domain, but Windows 7 does not.

However, [Azure AD Directory Services (AD DS)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/active-directory-ds/) is a relatively new feature (still in preview) that you can enable which turns AAD into something more similar to on prem AD. It has some limitations, including a fairly flat OU and GPO structure, however you can join machines to it.